# how do i override the url-pattern in a struts servlet mapping?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I am using Struts 1.2.7 and have the standard servlet mapping that uses `*.do` for my URLs.

```
<!-- Standard Action Servlet Mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I need to have a few custom URLs that do not use .do at the end, e.g., `/monitor/lb-healthcheck`. Is there a way to override the mapping, or add these specific paths to the web.xml file to map to specific Actions? This is a mature application, and it's not feasible at this point to change the mapping to `/` as the `url-pattern`.

Comment: Have you try adding a mapping just before that action mapping? `<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>monitor</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/monitor/lb-healthcheck</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

Comment: This totally works. Thank you! I would love to give you credit for providing the right answer, if you want to come back and add it to the question in the right place.

Comment: Thanks, added comment as the answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try adding a mapping just before that action mapping?

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>monitor</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/monitor/lb-healthcheck</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```